# Is there a way to have a batch file run within a windows form application in C#?

Tags: c#, batch-file, cmd

So anyways, I've been working on a batch IDE, and I was wondering if there was a good way to effectively embed the file into the form.

It would function sort of like a debug mode, where at any time, the user can click a button, and the batch file would load into the actual form.

Like the black cmd window would be embedded into the form...
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.FileName = "C:\\echo.cmd";
var p = Process.Start(psi);
Console.WriteLine(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```

And in `C:\echo.cmd` I have just basic `echo hello!`. When this code is executed - you'll see `hello!` received from batch's output stream.

Note that if executed command will wait for some input - `ReadToEnd()` can't return. In this case you should use `Process.OutputDataReceived` event.

Comment: It looks like the "Process" stuff requires some sort of using directive, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the process object and the StandardInput, StandardOutput and StandardError streams.
That is essentially all the command window is showing with some special handling of control characters.